# Angular 2 Material: Sidenav how to remove backdrop

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

So I am using angular cli with material design. I am trying to get rid of the backdrop with a sidenav and I thought it would be as simple as

```
.mat-sidenav-backdrop.mat-sidenav-shown{
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

however this isn't having any affect. I have tried display none, visibility hidden, etc. It seems like the style for the backdrop is being put out inline to a  tag and I would have thought the important would override it. However this isn't working... Anyone have any ideas that don't involve me stripping out the backdrop tag/ altering the styles via javascript during rendering?

Comment: Are you sure that's the right class selector? I don't see it being used anywhere in the source for the material sidenav.  https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/sidenav   

they refer to .mat-drawer-backdrop  &  .mat-drawer-shown to toggle on and off.  Its entirely possible I'm just misunderstanding how SCSS works though, because I never use it....

Comment: Yeah I am inspecting the end result in the browser and grabbing the css selector. This one contains a 60% black background color in the inspector and when I disable that in the browser I am good to go...   check out https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview it has the backdrop you can inspect that to see

Comment: Is `mode="side"` an option? It does not show the backdrop.

Comment: nope, trying to have it come up overtop of the content

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`::ng-deep` works great in this case, but it may be deprecated in the future. See [**here**](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep):

> The shadow-piercing descendant combinator is deprecated and support is
>   being removed from major browsers and tools. As such we plan to drop
>   support in Angular (for all 3 of /deep/, >>> and ::ng-deep). Until
>   then ::ng-deep should be preferred for a broader compatibility with
>   the tools.

The recommended way is to use [ViewEncapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation). In your component add the following encapsulation:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    ....
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Then your css will work and override the styles with your custom styles.

```
.mat-sidenav-backdrop.mat-sidenav-shown{
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Worked great, had to adjust some of the css for other items... All seems good now.

Comment: @Faisal While this appears to be current best practice, I believe it is a true statement that **anything** _may_ be deprecated in the future, but can you please cite an actual source that supports this point? (If not, then why mention it?)

Comment: @nothingisnecessary see the updated answer, I have added the reference.

Answer (score 24):

> `@Input() hasBackdrop: any` - Whether the drawer container should have a backdrop while one of the
>   sidenavs is open. If explicitly set to true, the backdrop will be
>   enabled for drawers in the side mode as well.
>
> (c) https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api

So you should just set property `[hasBackdrop]="false"` on `mat-sidenav-container`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as it doesn't modify the ViewEncapsulation and uses the sidenav api.

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple, without importing other things, without using encapsulation, just write [hasBackdrop]="false" inside your mat-sidenav-container tag.

`<mat-sidenav-container [hasBackdrop]="false">`

Answer (score 1):

Add `::ng-deep` to overrided the defualt prebuilt stylesheet css.

```
::ng-deep .mat-sidenav-backdrop.mat-sidenav-shown {
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

[Plunker demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/3Z9uEX?p=preview)

You can also use `display: none` to completely remove the backdrop from the DOM. In this case, `sidenav` will not close when clicked in backdrop area.

```
::ng-deep .mat-sidenav-backdrop.mat-sidenav-shown {
    display: none;
}
```

[Plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/JTqfPj?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

In relation to having no backdrop.
There are 2 solutions.

### Disabling the backdrop entirely:

As pointed out by: angularrocks.com above.

```
`<mat-sidenav-container hasBackdrop="false">`
```

**Note:** This will also stop the side-nav from closing when you click outside of it.

See: https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api

### Make back-drop transparent

In Angular 15, the following global css works:

```
.mat-drawer-backdrop.mat-drawer-shown {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

This also does not require the bad practice of adding `!important` in your CSS.

**Hint:**
Make sure you add your Material overrides after initializing the Material theme.

i.e.: in my styles.scss I have:

```
@import './app/styles/material.scss'; /* Loads main material theme */
@import './app/styles/material-classes.scss'; /* overrides material specific classes */
```

Comment: it works just we put '.mat-drawer-backdrop.mat-drawer-shown {
  background-color: transparent ;
}'  at the 'style.css', I tried to add @import s but I had an error: Cannot resolve directory 'styles'

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the opaque layer that appears when opening a modal or sidenav you need to modify the class that defined the property `visibility` for this element. In my case, I wanted to remove this layer that appeared when I opened sidenav, so I added:

```
.mat-drawer-shown {
visibility: hidden! important;
}
```

On `styles.scss`.

P.S.:
(This answer is for 2020's people haha)
Angular CLI version (10.1.3)